# Joomla 3.7.5 Disable Redis Cache

Tags: joomla-3.x, cache

after updating the Joomla site (hosted on a server with php set to 7.0.18) from version 3.7.4 to version 3.7.5, I found the Radis cache set. I can not disable cache from global configuration, and any value I try to set in global configuration after clicking on the save button, shows error 500 that the system does not support the "radis" cache.

I can not even figure out whether it can depend on Akeeba admin tools or joomla core.

Do you have any indication on this?

Thank you

Comment: Edit manually your configuration.php

Comment: Hi FFrewin, I already tryed to edit configuration.php file, but not found... I don't understund this.

Comment: Joomla can't work without configuration.php - so I guess you are somewhat confused on what you are doing. Ask for hands-on support from somewhere. Your hosting provider should be able to assist you as well.

Comment: Yes, Joomla can't work without configuration.php file.  The strange think, usually in global configuration ->setting cache there is a dropdow menu at "Manager Cache" where we choose a cache type: File or Redis. In my case, I see only "Redis" and there isn't "file". But in configuration file I see it.

Comment: OK.. I SOLVED. I re-checked the configuration file, and in the end, I found an incorrect value in the folder path for saving the cache file. So after I deleted this value, everything came back work fine.

Comment: Post exactly the case and what you did to solve your issue as answer below please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK.. I SOLVED. I re-checked the configuration file, and in the end, I found an incorrect value in the folder path for saving the cache file (public $cache_path). So I deleted this value, I left the field empty, everything went back to work.